# Online resources for premade WPF styles/control templates?

Tags: wpf, styles, controltemplate

When it comes to UI design I generally don't care to do custom styling (appearance-wise), I'm not much of an artist and I hate trying to come up with interesting color schemes and the like. Are there any online repositories of premade WPF styles and/or control templates? I could have sworn I saw one before but I can't find it now, it might be gone.

Just curious if you guys know of anything like this. It'd be great to be able to drop in a premade style into my application to spruce it up a bit.

Comment: Should probably be community wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [one](http://www.wpfstyles.com/).

Comment: Nothing WPF related on this site anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Here's [another](http://www.nukeation.com/reuxables.aspx?landing=reuxables).

Comment: This one has gone now too :(